# C# .NET 6 : custom service is unable to being resolved while its controller is activated

Tags: c#, .net-6.0

I'm learning .NET 6 REST API. I have this controller:

```cs
using GicBackend.Dto.Auth;
using GicBackend.Services.Auth;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace GicBackend.Controllers.Auth
{
    [ApiController]
    public class AuthController : Controller
    {
        private readonly AuthService _authService;

        public AuthController(AuthService authService)
        {
            _authService = authService;
        }

        [Route("[controller]/SignIn")]
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult SignIn([FromBody] SignInDto signInDto)
        {
            try
            {
                string token = _authService.SignIn(signInDto);

                Object bodyResponse = new
                {
                    token = token
                };

                return Ok(bodyResponse);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Unauthorized();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But every time I try to make a request to the endpoint, I get an error:

> Unable to resolve service for type 'GicBackend.Services.Auth.AuthService' while attempting to activate 'GicBackend.Controllers.Auth.AuthController'.

I don't know what to do, thank for you all answers.

Comment: Check if you've registered a service that you are using in constructor of controller. It can be registered with code `builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthService>(); `. It would be better to register using `Interface` and use `interface` in controller instead of `Class`. Refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Answer (score 0):

Have you registered that service yet?
Like this:

```
Services.AddScoped<IMyDependency, MyDependency>();
```

With your case:

```
Services.AddScoped<IAuthService, AuthService>();
```

Comment: As per the code provided in question, user does not use interface. So dependency should be resolved without interface. Like `builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthService>();`

Comment: I tried this but didn't work

Comment: the both, the only solution until now was to declare it hard coded without dependency injection, but i don't know if this is a good practice